# Convergence of a series involving $\arctan (1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what positive values of $a$ does the series $\sum (1/n -\arctan(1/n))^a $ converge ?

All the terms in the series are non negative and the terms are monotonic decreasing. Can I say for all positive $a$, the series is convergent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\arctan(\frac 1 n)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3n^3} + o(\frac{1}{n^3})
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{n}-\arctan(\frac 1 n)=\frac{1}{3n^3} + o(\frac{1}{n^3})
$$
and
$$
(\frac{1}{n}-\arctan(\frac 1 n))^\alpha=\frac{1}{3^{\alpha}n^{3\alpha}}( 1+ o(1)).
$$
Thus
$$
(\frac{1}{n}-\arctan(\frac 1 n))^\alpha \sim \frac{1}{3^{\alpha}n^{3\alpha}}
$$
and the series converges iff $3\alpha > 1$ iff $\alpha > \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Michelle. I was trying all the tests like Ratio, Raabe , Cauchy root etc. The series approach didn't strike me. Thank you for the neat answer.

Comment: @LawrenceMano My pleasure ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor expansion we have
$$\frac1n-\arctan\frac1n=\frac{1}{3n^3}+O(n^{-5}).$$
Then you can compare the series with $\sum n^{-3a}$.